# Listing and Linking contents of a folder in JSP doesn't work

Tags: list, jsp, hyperlink, download

I have to make a Web Application for downloading files from a folder.I use Tomcat as a server.I wrote a JSP page for listing the content of my data folder,and I tried to make links for each file from this folder.

The JSP page is this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.io.File,java.io.IOException,java.util.*,java.io.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Contents <br>
<% File f = new File("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\eclipse\\app\\PTW\\WebContent\\data\\"); // current directory

File[] files = f.listFiles();
 for (File file : files) { 
    if (file.isDirectory()) {  
        //System.out.print("directory:");
    } else {
        %>
        <a href="<%=file.getAbsolutePath()%>" target="_blank"><br> <%=file.getName() %>
         </a>

    <%  
    } 
} 

 %>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that downloading these files is working only in I.E. and only if user selects Right CLick - Save target As.

So my way to do this is wrong!But I don't understand why?**How to force downloading files from this JSP?**

**Thank You!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must know that the path to the file on the **file system** is a different path than the **URL**. The file system is only known by your server, the URL is the path which is accessed by browsers.

Let's say your file is in `/opt/tomcat/webapps/myApp/folder/file.jpg` and you are running your Tomcat on `www.example.com`. If you generate (through JSP) a link like

```
<a href="/opt/tomcat/webapps/myApp/folder/file.jpg">Download File</a>
```

Your browser will see this path as:

```
www.example.com/opt/tomcat/webapps/myApp/folder/file.jpg
```

Your browser will not find the file. The URL the browser would neet to find it is:

```
www.example.com/myApp/folder/file.jpg
```

Which consists of

- the domain `www.example.com`
- the servlet context `myApp`
- the path inside the application to the file `folder/file.jpg`

So you need to build the path `/myApp/folder/file.jpg` in your JSP. You can do it this way:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/folder/file.jpg">Download</a>
```

I use [Expression Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language) here instead of scriptlets. This is considered better style as it improves maintaineance and readability.

Note: This will only work if your File is inside the webapplication directory (`myApp`). If it is outside, you will need a servlet to stream your files to the client, but that is an other story.

Comment: **thank you very much w4rumy**.

now i understand why it didn't work.
you told me how to buid the path to a **specific file**,in your case _file.jpg_ .but now i need to make a list of content,with links for each file from my folder.as i did in my code with **file.getName()**.

I didn't manage to concatenate the **file.getName()** to the **${pageContext.request.contextPath}/folder/**. Is it possible?

Comment: @AdiCrainic List the contents of the directory is possible, however this is a different topic. If you get stuck somewhere, feel free to post another question on Stackoverflow. You Are Welcome!